# Scanner does not work properly with UTF-16 encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-16

I have written some small code snippet with output console set as **UTF-16** and the Scanner does not work properly
[image]

You can see an `InputMismatchException` raised. However, code works perfectly with *Cp1252* and *UTF-8*.
Could anyone give me the explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try instantiating the Scanner with the constructor that takes an encoding name?

Comment: Print the line you read - possibly you see that the program did not receive `"abc"`.

Comment: @nitind tried but error has been still there